# find maximum value and minimum value

Tags: maxima-minima

> $y=x^2$ and $D_f=(0,2]$.

So, my interval is $0<x^2<=2$

But, according to my book it has no minimum values. But, it has maximum value which is $2^2=4$

According to me, it should have minimum value either. Cause, $1$ exists in that interval also.So, $1$ is minimum value. But, why they said that there's no minimum value?

Comment: What does it have to do with $1$?? $0.5$ is also there and what?

Comment: @Saad $1$ is minimum value. That's what I think. My question was why my book said there's no minimum value?

Comment: We have $f(D_f)=(0,4]$. Hence $ \inf f(D_f)$ exists and $=0.$ But  $ \min f(D_f)$ does not exist.

Comment: @logloglogx 's comment was useful for me. But, he had removed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is increasing on this interval (prove it).

Suppose the minimum occured at $x > 0$. Consider $x/2$ - uh-oh.

See the problem? No minimum exists on $(0, 2].$